# Friend methods as Constant

Tags: c++, class, constants, friend

Why can't I declare a friend function as `const`?

```
//Types.h
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <ostream>

class Player
{
public:
    //constructors
    Player();
    Player(const std::string&, unsigned short);

    //operator overload
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Player&);
//                  (I can't declare it as const)

    //getter
    const std::string& get_id() const;

private:
    std::string id;
    unsigned short lvl;
};
```

```
//Types.cpp
#include "Types.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

/*other definitions*/

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Player& print)
{
    out << "Player: " << std::setw(6) << print.id << " | " << "Level: " << print.lvl;
    return out;
}
```

I mean, if I want to call `operator<<` on a constant variable or in a constant function, I will get an error because `operator<<` is not *constant*, even if it doesn't change anithing inside the class.

Comment: Your `Player& print` is not constant.

Comment: I know: my example shows that the friend method could modify any variable if it is not declared as *constant*, so I can't understand why my compiler does not allow me to declare it as a `const` function

Comment: No, your example shows that you can modify `print` since it is not declared `const`. Since the friend function is not a member function, there is no `this` variable in it that could be `const` and therefore, you cannot add the `const` modifier to the function itself.

Comment: @flyx what I mean is that I declare a function as `const` if I want it to be called in another `const` function or on a parameter passed by `const` reference, but if this function is a `friend` I can't do it because it can't be declared as `const`. So (don't think to my example) if I want to call `operator<<` (which doesn't modify any variable) on a `const` variable, I can't do that because `operator<<` can't be declared as `const`

Comment: I couldn't fully understand your comments. but I think what you need is `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Player& print)`

Comment: @anonymous I edited the post to make it a bit more clear... I don't know how to explain you if you can't understand this!

Comment: You _can_ call your `operator<<` overload from a `const`-qualified member function as is.  As @flyx said, it's a free function, so the function itself can't be `const` qualified since there's no `this` object to be treated as `const`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But `operator<<` is not a member - it's a free function.  So there's no base object that it's not modifying.

```
int myFunc() const {
    return 3;
}
```

Also gets an error from the compiler:

```
error: non-member function 'int myFunc()' cannot have cv-qualifier
```

Your version of `operator<<` is also quite strange as it doesn't output anything to the stream it's supposed to, preferring instead to output things to `std::cout`!

I think you should reconsider what you hope to achieve, as you're trying to do something non-standard.  If you just want a method that writes the contents of your class to std::cout, then just do that, rather than overloading the operator.

Note that if you had some other iostream, you'd be surprised that nothing goes into it!

```
std::ofstream myFile("my_path");
myFile << Player;
```

Comment: The fact that it didn't *output* anything to the string was just an error...

Comment: But could I call this `function` on a constant object even if it is not declared as `const`?

Comment: you're not calling on an object - you're passing an object (reference) to it.  And that parameter is declared `const` so you have declared that you will not modify it.  The `const` modifier for a method says that this method will not modify the object of which it is a member.

Comment: You might consider that `const` after a method declaration is applied to the hidden `this` parameter that is passed to every non-static method.

Comment: @ Arunas thank you! I didn't consider the fact that I *can't* call a friend function on an object but I can *only* pass parameters to it

Comment: @Foxel, you might want to read about this in more detail here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend - note that they even discuss your use case.

Comment: @Foxel - and if you find that the answer is correct, and helped you out of your problem, you can mark it as 'accepted'